# How to properly call functions in templates?

Tags: python, function, templates, web.py

Okay, I've learned a little and am now able to replicate my site in web.py, BUT I don't like how I'm doing it in certain places.

1) I want to be able to call the templates without calling Main each time.

2) I want to be able to call the functions from the Layout.

Any advice to the above would be helpful, thank you in advance.

Below is a shortened version of the code to give you an idea of what's going on.  Please let me know if I missed posting something important.

code.py:

```
import web
import Universal
import Navigation
import Content
import Versions


urls = (
    '/favicon.ico', 'icon',
    '/', 'index',
    '/Section1/index', 'Section1',
    '/Section2/index', 'Section2',
    '/Section3/index', 'Section3'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=True)
render = web.template.render('templates/')#, base='Layout')

static = web.template.render('static/')

Main = web.template.render('templates/')
Section1 = web.template.render('templates/Section1/')
Section2 = web.template.render('templates/Section2/')
Section3 = web.template.render('templates/Section3/')

class static:
    def GET(self):
        return static()

#class icon:
#    def GET(self):
#        return static.favicon()

class index:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '0'
        vSection = '0'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        return Main.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

class Section1:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '1'
        vSection = '1'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        return Main.Section1.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

class Section2:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '2'
        vSection = '2'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        return Main.Section2.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

class Section3:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '3'
        vSection = '3'
        vHead = Universal.getHead(vSection)
        vHeader = Universal.getHeader()
        vNavBar = Universal.getNavBar()
        vNavigation = Navigation.getNavigation(vLevel)
        vContent = Content.getContent(vLevel)
        vVersions = Versions.getVersions(vLevel)
        vFooter = Universal.getFooter()
        #return render.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)
        return Main.Section3.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)
```

templates/Layout.html:

```
$def with (vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

<html>
<head>
    $:vHead
</head>
<body id="idBody">
    <table id="idTableMain">
        <tr id="idHeaderRow">
            <td id="idHeaderRowCenter" colspan="3">
                $:vHeader
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="idNavigationRow">
            <td id="idNavigationBar" colspan="3">
                $:vNavBar
            </td>
        </tr>               
        <tr id="idCenterRow">
            <td id="idCenterRowLeft">
                <h4>
                    Navigation
                </h4>
                $:vNavigation
            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowMain">
                $:vContent
            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowRight">
                <h4>
                    Information
                </h4>
                This was written with Python 2.7 and web.py.<br><br>
                Other versions of this page are here:<br>
                $:vVersions
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="idFooterRow">
            <td id="idFooterMain" colspan="3">
                $:vFooter
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Universal.py

```
def getHead(vSection):
    vResult = '<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">'
    vResult += '<link href=' + getCSS(vSection) + ' rel=\"stylesheet\" type="text/css">'
    return vResult

def getCSS(vSection):
    if vSection == '1':
        vResult = '/static/Section1/Section1.css'
    elif vSection == '2':
        vResult = '/static/Section2/Section2.css'
    elif vSection == '3':
        vResult = '/static/Section3/Section3.css'
    else:
        vResult = '/static/Main.css'
    return vResult

def getHeader():
    vResult = '<img id=\"idLogo\" src=' + getLogo() + '>'
    return vResult
def getNavBar():
    vResult = '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/index\'>Home</a>'
    vResult += '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/Section1/index\'>Web Programming</a>'
    vResult += '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/Section2/index\'>Private Projects</a>'
    vResult += '<a class=\'navBar\' href=\'/Section3/index\'>Downloadable Projects</a>'
    return vResult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.py templates use a white-list to identify functions which can be executed within a template. You can add to this by creating a dict and passing it into your renderers. For example:

```
common_globals = {'getHeader': Universal.getHeader,
                  'getCSS': Universal.getCSS,
                  'getHead': Universal.getHead,
                  'getNavBar': Universal.getNavBar}
Main = web.template.render('templates/')
Section1 = web.template.render('templates/Section1/', globals=common_globals)
Section2 = web.template.render('templates/Section2/', globals=common_globals)
Section3 = web.template.render('templates/Section3/', globals=common_globals)
```

Then, within you `Layout.html` you can do:

```
$def with(page, level, section)
<html>
<head>
    $:getHead(section)
</head>
etc....
```

...and then your call in `code.py` for class Section2 looks like:

```
class Section2(object):
    def GET(self):
        return Main.Section2.Layout(page=0, level=2, section=2)
```

(Actually, I don't think you ever need to call Main, just render as `return Section2.Layout(0, 2, 2)`

Repeat for the other sections and update your Layout to make calls to your functions directly and it will work.

Comment: THANK YOU @pbuck!  I kept finding pieces of the stuff for the dict, but couldn't piece it together that it was what I needed.  Looking forward to trying that when I can.

Comment: For the Main vs Section2 issue, how you were suggesting is how I had intended to do it, but I kept getting something like "no item name Layout exists here" and had to do Main.Section2....etc to get to the different templates.

I'll reattempt after your first suggestion. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `Main` vs. `Section1` etc. If they're only different pages, then perhaps you should use a single renderer (`Main`), and have that renderer call the template page (`Layout`), providing different parameter values each time. If they represent different page styles (like 'home page', 'help pages', etc.) then you can use same renderer ('Main') with different template pages ('home.html', 'help.html', etc.) providing different parameter values to each particular page instance (i.e., Main.help(title="Login Help", description=...), Main.help('Privacy', '...')

Comment: Part of the point of this project is to mimic an existing webpage, so I'm trying to find the way to retain the file structure as much as possible.  Under the current model there is a layout (or template) for each directory level, so the original plan was to call a renderer of Section2_4 something like this:

Section2_4 = web.template.render('templates/Section2/Section4/')
as opposed to
return Main.Section2.Section4.Layout(vHead, vHeader, vNavBar, vNavigation, vContent, vVersions, vFooter)

but it may be the python way to do unique Layouts such as Layout2_4, in the templates folder.

Comment: Using different templates, one per directory, works too -- and might make sense, if each directory needs to be formatted differently. If each directory is the "same" except for titles / headers / data, then using a single template would make things easier IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Credit realy goes to @pbuck on this one.  The first part of the problem is solved by using a dict and updating everything to match that:

dict in code.py:

```
common_globals = {'getHead': Universal.getHead,
                    'getCSS': Universal.getCSS,
                    'getHeader': Universal.getHeader,
                    'getLogo': Universal.getLogo,
                    'getNavBar': Universal.getNavBar,
                    'getFooter': Universal.getFooter,
                    'getNavigation': Navigation.getNavigation,
                    'getContent': Content.getContent,
                    'getVersions': Versions.getVersions
                    }
```

reference to page in code.py

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        vPage = '0'
        vLevel = '0'
        vSection = '0'
        return Main.Layout(vPage, vLevel, vSection)
```

templates/Layout.html
$def with (vPage, vLevel, vSection)

```
<html>
<head>
    $:getHead(vSection)
</head>
<body id="idBody">
    <table id="idTableMain">
        <tr id="idHeaderRow">
            <td id="idHeaderRowCenter" colspan="3">
                $:getHeader()
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="idNavigationRow">
            <td id="idNavigationBar" colspan="3">
                $:getNavBar()
            </td>
        </tr>               
        <tr id="idCenterRow">
            <td id="idCenterRowLeft">
                <h4>
                    Navigation
                </h4>
                $:getNavigation(vLevel)
            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowMain">
                $:getContent(vLevel+'_'+vPage+'P')
            </td>
            <td id="idCenterRowRight">
                <h4>
                    Information
                </h4>
                This was written with Python 2.7 and web.py.<br><br>
                Other versions of this page are here:<br>
                $:getVersions(vLevel+'_'+vPage+'P')
            </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="idFooterRow">
            <td id="idFooterMain" colspan="3">
                $:getFooter()
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand its not fancy, but this was a great learning exercise.  Only thing left is the renderer issue, and that's just more about WHERE the work happens in Code.py

I'll probably post that as a separate question.

Comment: glad it worked for you! Feel free to 'accept' my answer.